# Does RTLCopyMemory work in Vista?

Tags: winapi, com, vb6, windows-vista

I've noticed that RTL*Move*Memory seems to work just fine. But when I try to use RTL*Copy*Memory I get: "Can't find DLL entry point RtlCopyMemory in kernel32". Here is my declare:

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMem Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlCopyMemory" ( _
    ByVal dest As Long, _
    ByVal source As Long, _
    ByVal bytLen As Long)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RtlCopyMemory` is [provided inline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366535%28VS.85%29.aspx). It is defined in `winnt.h` as `memcpy`. This means that it's not included in a Win32 DLL, it's part of the C runtime library. You could try importing `memcpy` from `c:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll`.

Comment: Wouldn't memcpy use _CDECL calling convention not _STDCALL? So you wouldn't be able to call it from VB6 (unless you used Matt Curland's heavy duty magic techniques)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use `RtlMoveMemory`? It works just like `RtlCopyMemory` except that it handles overlapped memory in a different fashion.

Bruce McKinney [pioneered](http://vb.mvps.org/hardcore/html/bringyourhatchet.htm) the use of RtlMoveMemory over 10 years ago and it's been [standard](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129947) for VB6 memory copying ever since.

Comment: Because according to MS RtlCopyMemory performs faster, so I wanted to test the difference.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a declaration for `memcpy` you could share with us? What were the speed results?

Comment: Not yet, that was what I was working from: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/… and if you google "declare sub RtlCopyMemory" you get an few hits. But it wasn't working so I thought I would just try to verify if should be working:)

Comment: Note: Dependency walker can't find an entry for RtlCopyMemory in Kernel32.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem, so I thought I could answer.

RtlCopyMemory in kernel32.dll should be an [Export Forward](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx) into ntdll,
but somehow guys at MS [missed that one](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/100464/missing-export-rtlcopymemory-in-lib-for-64-bit-kernel32-dll) <strike>on x64 version of Vista (dunno how it's on x86)</strike> (see below).

You can try importing it directly from ntdll, if it's only for your needs.

EDIT: the method I mean is not exported, but with Symbols it's visible in ntdll as *RtlCopyMemoryNonTemporal*

EDIT2: Just to be sure I've checked some things, here's summary:

- both RtlCopyMemory and RtlCopyMemoryNonTemporal are exported from ntdll.dll in x64 Vista's (plain, SP1, SP2)
- there is export forward for RtlCopyMemory in kernel32.dll in x64 Vista's
- there is **unexported** RtlCopyMemoryNonTemporal in ntdll.dll in x86 Vista's

So it all should be if you're writing x64 application.

P.S. I was wrong about x64 vs x86, because I was compiling x86 app, and running it on x64 (WOW mode),
so it used 32-bit version of kernel32, ntdll and not the x64 one.